# Strategy to test WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, nunit, moq

What is the preferred testing strategy for testing WCF services?

Should I be implementing the services then hosting them and then testing them?

Or

Should I implement the service, then test the service DLLS and then host them?

Can you please recommend a good WCF testing strategy?

I have implemented few WCF services which will be deployed under intranet, hosted using wshttpbinding and are running under windows services.

Comment: How about doing the same kind of testing you would do for any other application?

Answer (score 8):

What I have typically done is to create two sets of tests. One of them being *unit* tests, where I create an instance of the service implementation, and test it. This completely bypasses WCF.

Then I have a separate test project that I end up calling *integration* tests, where I will start up an instance of the actual WCF service (usually in a self-hosted manner), and create an instance of a WCF client, and call the client and verify the result. This uses WCF, basically just querying my services over localhost.

I find that this gives the best amount of coverage in tests, since sometimes you end up with WCF errors that you wouldn't have normally caught if you bypassed WCF.

Comment: Great. Thanks.  How will I mock the data layer interfaces used in the WCF services?

Comment: In my particular case, my service implementations have their data layer Dependency Injected into them. In my Unit tests, I mock them out with Moq and constructor-inject them into my service implementation. My Integration tests however do no mocking of the data layer. This is really specific to my case though; our integration tests really test the full application, from the WCF request down to the DB and back up. However using something like Unity for dependency injection, it wouldn't be hard to run the Intg tests off a different Unity config that would inject a mock data layer.

Answer (score 2):

My WCF service didn't have any logic in it. it always delegate the calls to another service.

So I could test the service without any reference to WCF.

This [approach](http://blog.kellybrownsberger.com/archive/2009/03/17/43.aspx) worked for me to test the wcf service.

E.g.

```
public class CalcService
{
   public int Add(int x, int y) 
   {
       return x+y;
   }
}
```

Calc Service Host

```
public class CalculaterService
{

   private CalcService _calcService;
   public CalcService CalcService {get { return _calcService;}}

   public CalculaterService(CalcService calcService) 
   {
      _calcService = calcService;
   }

   public int Add(int x, int y) 
   {
     return CalcService.Add(x, y);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF SVCTraceViewer to view and trace the wcf operations

check this link also for detail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx